# Screen Rotation Issue on Ubuntu 23.10 with MSI GE70 and GTX760M

Tags: nvidia, graphics, power-management, screen, display-rotation

I'm currently facing an issue with my MSI GE70 laptop running Ubuntu 23.10, equipped with a GTX760M graphics card. Whenever I disconnect the laptop from power and switch to battery mode, the screen rotates by 90 degrees automatically. This means that to restore the original screen orientation, I have to reconnect and disconnect the power four times.

This issue persists regardless of whether I use Nvidia drivers (version 470) or the x.org drivers. I've tried several troubleshooting steps such as checking the display and power management settings, but haven't found a solution yet.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this. Has anyone experienced a similar issue or can offer advice on how to prevent the screen from rotating upon switching to battery power?

Thank you in advance for your help!